# Solr read timed out in client environment

Tags: java, solr, timeout, solrj

we've got following error when we are trying to index(add) single document to our Knowledge Base project. It works fine on our test environment but with any attempt to add index in client environment it throws Read timeout error.

```
2013-07-03 15:30:19,273 org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.commit(SolrServer.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.commit(SolrServer.java:154)
```

I compared solrconfig.xml files and there are no differences. We have Tomcat servers on both environments.

Do you have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the client being able to connect to the Solr server in general.

Have you confirmed that you can connect to the Solr server from the client environment directly? Look at firewall settings, etc.

Also ensure that the code deployed to the client environment is attempting to access Solr using the correct Url.

Comment: I can connect to solr directly, and I can search for articles so solr query seems to work fine. The problem is when I try to add/edit documents so it looks like some issue in adding index or commit operation. Added documents are not big-sized.
Thanks for feedback Paige